# Liquid: how can I change my Shopify theme's language programatically?

Tags: shopify, liquid, multilingual

I have a Shopify theme that has a default language of English. I know how to change the site's language once logged in as an admin, but I want to know how I can programmatically change the theme's language (via a button in the front end).

I'd like the site visitor to be able to switch between languages at will (English and French). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible for the moment, you can use an app, [weglot](https://apps.shopify.com/weglot) for example is a good app to achieve this.

Comment: If WeGlot can do this, it is possible I presume.